# Log images with DDP strategy in pytorch lightning with WandbLogger object

Tags: python, logging, predict, pytorch-lightning, wandb

I'm building a model with pytorch lightning and I'm using the Distributed Data Parallel (DDP) strategy on 2 GPU for accelerating the process. After the fitting of the model, I need to return 4 pairs of prediction with structure `(output, ground_truth)` that are two 2d vectors (images), while the input of the `predict_step` method is a batch of a single element loaded once a time with a dataloader object.
Considering my specific settings the GPUs execute 2 prediction each once at a time and the results are returned.

With the following code I'm tring to store all the prediction's outputs with Wheights&Biases library that allows to do it natively, but I'm having some problems because only 2 images are stored.

```
def on_predict_batch_end(self, outputs, batch, batch_idx):
        gt, pred, axis, idx_slice = outputs
        gt = gt.squeeze().cpu().numpy()
        pred = pred.squeeze().cpu().numpy()
        if axis != 0:
            gt = np.rot90(gt, 2)
            gt = np.flip(gt, 1)
            pred = np.rot90(pred, 2)
            pred = np.flip(pred, 1)
        self.logger.log_image(
            key="eval_output",
            images=[gt, pred],
            caption=[
                f"gt_data_{axis}_{idx_slice}",
                f"output_model_{axis}_{idx_slice}",
            ],
        )
```

Have you some ideas on how to fix this problems? The images' names are all different so images are not overridden

I tried also to use the Callback class provided by pytorch lightning but the situation remains the same. Using only one GPU the logging procedure works